# Returning list from a function in python

Tags: python, list, dictionary

Task :With dictionary write function frekv which returns occurrence of numbers

This is my code:

```
def frekv(n):
    b={}
    for i in n:
        if i in b:
             b[i] +=1
        else:
            b[i]=1
    return b

x = map(frekv,[5, 2, 4, 4, 3, 1, 3, 8]) 
print (list(x))
```

Result: {5: 1, 2: 1, 4: 2, 3: 2, 8: 1, 1: 1}

This is not a right way to return it, is there any way I could return that whole list.

Comment: `return b` needs to be indented. `b` is a dictionary, not a list.

Comment: Mistake n is a dictionary in function

Comment: Why are you calling `map()`? The function expects the argument to be a list, but you're calling it separately with each element of the list.

Comment: Should I make b=[] something like that to store number and number of occurances

Comment: No, a dictionary is the correct way to store the information. There's also a library `collections.Counter()` that does this.

Comment: What you wrote would be the result of `frekv([5, 2, 4, 4, 3, 1, 3, 8])` without using `map()`

Comment: `return b` still needs to be indented, otherwise it's not in the function.

Comment: But I need to use map

Comment: map is not the right tool for this. It returns a separate result for each input, it can't combine them.

Comment: What is the result you're trying to get?

Comment: @Momo if you need to use `map`, you must specify it in the question, you can't withhold vital information from your question and only put it in comments.

Comment: The task doesn't say anything about using `map`.

Comment: Probably he is referring `map` in the sense of `HashMap`? It would be a dictionary then!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably you meant something like this:

```
def frekv(n):
    b={}
    for i in n:
        if i in b:
             b[i] +=1
        else:
            b[i]=1
    return b

x = frekv([5, 2, 4, 4, 3, 1, 3, 8]) 
print(x)
```

Output:

```
{5: 1, 2: 1, 4: 2, 3: 2, 1: 1, 8: 1}
```

Comment: He wrote in a comment "I need to use map"

Comment: With dictionary write function frekv which returns occurrence of numbers

Comment: I dont have to use x = map(frekv,[5, 2, 4, 4, 3, 1, 3, 8]) like this?

Comment: No, you don't have to use like this. This `map()` is a different thing, you only need a dictionary here.

Comment: @Momo Of course not. That calls `frekv(5)` then `frekv(2)`, etc. But the argument to `frekv` is supposed to be a list, not a number.

Comment: @Momo Try executing this code and see if this is the output that you want?

Comment: @Barmar he has also provided the output in the question and I think this answer is producing the same output.

Comment: It is, this is my first time with python I was learning C before. I tought I have to use map() something to be good. Thank you

Comment: @Momo No `map()` in Python is different from map() in C/C++. In Python, it is known as a dictionary.